# Restrict editing to certain columns when updating a record

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I want to implement a grid using Telerik UI that is used to display/update/create records. The grid is configured to use in-cell editing, and for updating, only some of the columns are editable, but when the user adds a record, every cell of the newly added row should be editable. I have already tried to hook the `Edit` event and make the field editable. However, by doing so, not only the *Title* cell of the new row becomes editable, but also the existing *Title* cells.

The relevant code sections of the view can be found below.

***Data.cshtml***

```html
<script>
    'use strict';

    function onEdit(event) {
        if (event.model.isNew()) {
            event.model.fields.Title.editable = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataViewModel>()
    .Name("DataGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(model => model.Title);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Description);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Count);
    })
    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Events(events => events
        .Edit("onEdit")
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read("DataRead", "Data")
        .Create("DataCreate", "Data")
        .Update("DataUpdate", "Data")
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(x => x.Id);
            model.Field(x => x.Title).Editable(false);
        })
    )
)
```

*Kendo UI v2020.2.617*, *Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core 2020.2.617*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be rather than setting the model editable property and hooking the onEdit event, you could try the following which will call a js function to determine if the column should be editable:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataViewModel>()
    .Name("DataGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(model => model.Title).Editable("titleEditable");
        columns.Bound(model => model.Description);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Count);
    })
    //truncated for brevity


<script>
        function titleEditable(dataItem) {
            return dataItem.isNew();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You are completely right, `model` is available via the `event` parameter, this was a mistake by me while composing the example for this post. Nonetheless, this does not answer my original question on how to only define the new row as editable.

Comment: So, if you put a breakpoint or debugger statement in that onEdit function, when the row is new is the Title.editable false before being set to true? Also, couldn't you update the function to simply Title.editable = event.model.isNew() ?  I'll append this and another option to try into my answer to try out

Comment: I just meant have you actually verified it at run time. Just trying to help you debug it

Comment: Please remove the first two options using `onEdit()` from your answer, as they lead the unwanted behavior I have described in my question, The third option, however, works quite nicely, thank you very much!